# Como executar SQL com Entity Framework?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Tentei executar um comando `SQL` pelo `Entity Framework`, tentei das seguintes formas:

```
string cmd = "UPDATE t0071_compra SET t0071_status = 'Enviado' WHERE t0071_id_compra = 4 AND t0020_id_empresa = 1";
context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(cmd);
context.SaveChanges();
```

---

```
string cmd = "UPDATE t0071_compra SET t0071_status = 'Enviado' WHERE t0071_id_compra = 4 AND t0020_id_empresa = 1";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(cmd);
context.SaveChanges();
```

mas em nenhum das formas funcionou, estou usando Mysql, o que esta errado ai?

Comment: Apresenta algum erro? se for `UPDATE` é o segundo jeito!

Comment: nao apresenta nehum erro, mas nao tem nenhum efeito

Comment: alessandre é muito estranho, não ter efeito, talvez não satisfaça a condição! verifique se retorna `int rows = context.Database.ExecuteSQLCommand(cmd)` maior do que 0, se retornar ele atualizou alguma coisa se retornou 0 ele não teve nenhuma alteração?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você deseja executar um comando que não retorna resultados (não é um SELECT)

basta utilizar `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`, onde **DbContext** é o seu contexto.

Não é necessário utilizar o método `SaveChanges` neste caso, porque o comando já irá executar diretamente no banco e não irá afetar as entidades do EF no contexto.

Lembrando que depois de executar o comando desta forma você precisa atualizar as entidades manualmente (via `DbContext.Entry(entity).Reload();`) caso deseje utilizar os valores atualizados no mesmo lifecycle da aplicação (ou seja, antes de descartar e reiniciar o contexto)

Seguem alguns links falando sobre:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081244/reload-an-entity-and-all-navigation-property-association-dbset-entity-framework

Comment: entao, da forma que utilizei, deveria funcionar, testei sem o saveChanges, mas tb nao funcionou

Comment: Você verificou manualmente no banco ? O where está certo ? Rode o comando direto no MySQL e veja se atualiza